# definition of total variation of a complex measure does not depend on any algebra generating the sigma-algebra of that measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

While studying a course on "Vector Measures", I come to this problem:

Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, generated by an algebra $\mathcal{A}$. Its total variation $|\mu|$ is given by
$$\tag{1}|\mu|(E) = \sup\limits_{\{S_i\}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|\mu(S_i)|,$$
where supremum runs over all finite [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) $\{S_i\}$ in $\Sigma$ of $E$ (which means that each $S_i$ belongs to $\Sigma$).

Now, for $E \in \mathcal{A}$, I want to prove that
$$\tag{2}|\mu|(E) = \sup\limits_{\{A_i\}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n|\mu(A_i)|,$$
where supremum runs over all finite partitions $\{A_i\}$ in $\mathcal{A}$ of $E$.

It is clear that "supremum in (2)" $\leq$ "supremum in (1)". Can anybody give me a hint for the reverse inequality?

Comment: @PostNoBills: Yes, I miss that information. If not, we can't have any finite partitions of $E$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that for every $S \in \Sigma$, and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $|\mu|(S \Delta A) < \epsilon$.

Note by definition of a complex measure that $|\mu|(\Omega) < \infty$, where $\Omega$ is the whole set.  Consider
$$ \mathcal S = \{S \in \Sigma: \forall \epsilon>0 \exists A \in \mathcal A: |\mu|(S \Delta A) < \epsilon) \} $$
Show that $\mathcal S$ is a sigma-algebra, and since $\Sigma$ is the minimal sigma-algebra containing $\mathcal A$, we are done.

The trickiest bit of proving $\mathcal S$ is a sigma-algebra will be the countable union axiom, and this is where you will need $|\mu|(\Omega) < \infty$.  By the Dynkin $\pi$-$\lambda$ argument (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system), you need only check the case when the sets are disjoint.  But then for any $\epsilon>0$, the union of all except finitely many of them has $|\mu|$-measure bounded by $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: I agree with you that for every $S\in \Sigma$ and for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $|\mu|(S\Delta A) < 3$. Could you show me how we can apply that result to this problem? As a note: I know that if there is $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $A\subset S$ such that $|\mu|(S\backslash A) < \epsilon$, then we can get the conclusion after an $\epsilon$ argument for $\sup$.

Comment: But since $|\mu|$ is an unsigned measure, don't we have $|\mu|(S\setminus A) \le |\mu|(S \Delta A) < \epsilon$?

Comment: I mean that I need $A \subset S$! If not, I can't get a partition of $E$ in $\mathcal{A}$ from a partion of $E$ in $\Sigma$.

Comment: So to finish, suppose
$$\mu|(E) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n|\mu(S_i)| + \epsilon,$$
for some finite partition $\{S_i\}$ in $\Sigma$ of $E$.  Find a sequence of sets $A_i \in \mathcal A$ with $|\mu|(S_i \Delta A_i) < 2^{-i}\epsilon$.  Let $B_i = E \cap \left(A_i \setminus \bigcup_{j=i+1}^n A_j\right)$.  Then it isn't going to be too hard to show that $|\mu|(S_i \Delta B_i) < 3\times 2^{-i}\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! At first, I see this argument quite tricky. Then after following it, I figure out why you choose those $A_i$, why you put those $B_i$. Oh, excellent!